# How to make jdbc connection pool using tomcat server in spring boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I made a simple spring boot project and i want to access mysql database.I am using tomcat connection pool for database pooling. I gave following properties in my server.xml file which is in tomcat/conf folder.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyLocalDB"
  global="jdbc/MyLocalDB"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demoData"
  username="root"
  password="root"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="20"
  minIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"/>
```

and in tomcat/conf/context.xml-

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/MyLocalDB"
            global="jdbc/MyLocalDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

And this is my main spring boot application class file look like-

```
package com.tomcat.pool;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJDBCConnectionPoolApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringJDBCConnectionPoolApp.class, args);
}


@Resource(name="jdbc/myLocalDB")
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
}
```

webServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Resource(name="jdbc/MyLocalDB")
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, name from user");

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        out.write("<html>");
        out.write("<body>");

        out.write("<h3>Database Records</h3>");
        while(rs.next())  {
            out.write("id: " + rs.getInt("id") + " ");
            out.write("name: " + rs.getString("name") + " ");
            out.write("</br>");
        }

        //lets print some DB information
        out.write("<h3>Database Meta Data</h3>");
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();
        out.write("Database Product: " + 
 metaData.getDatabaseProductName() + "<br/>");
        out.write("Database Version: " + 
 metaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion() + "."
                + metaData.getDatabaseMinorVersion() + "<br/>");
        out.write("Database Driver: " + metaData.getDriverName() + "
 <br/>");
        out.write("Database Driver version: " + metaData.getDriverMajorVersion() + "."
                + metaData.getDriverMinorVersion() + "<br/>");
        out.write("Database user: " + metaData.getUserName());
        out.write("</html>");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in closing DB resources");
        }
    }
}
}
```

but i can't access the database. can you point out what is the problem with this code.

Comment: Do you see the "dataSource not found" message getting printed ?

Comment: @Amir_Af no, when i deployed it on tomcat server i got no errors. and no "dataSource not found" message printed.

Comment: Ok, what about trying debug ? why you don't install tomcat plugin in your IDE and put break points? if you are not able to access DB  you should get some exception ? what is the exception ?

Comment: @Amir_Af i edited my code and now i am trying to access the dataSource like this but my application is not able to read the database resource from server.xml. is there any way to read that resource ?

Comment: Since it’s spring boot app  I would suggest you to do it in the Spring way. You need to create new class with @configuration annotation and add datasource bean with the configuration you want . The configuration properties should be placed in your application.properties. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: i already did that by application.properties and my datasource got connect successfully. i just want to do it in this way using tomcat database connection pool. i also did this in a web-servlet but i am not able do it in spring boot application. i will add that web-servlet in my question.

Comment: You can use tomcat connection pool also by doing this the way I told you . You just need to set the tomcat driver and then. This way if at some point you will want to take the app out of tomcat and let’s say to put it on a cloud it will still use the tomcat connection pool

Comment: @Amir_Af what do you mean by tomcat driver and where do i have to set it ?

Comment: sorry my mistake. I mean you need to use tomcat datasource. org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource  and set the desired values like maxActive connection, maxidle and so on . this way it will use tomcat connection pool mechanism